# Cross section area

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

A long plank, with a $1 \times 1$ cross section, is cut as shown below. The region of the cut is a parallelogram with sides $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}.$ Find the area of the parallelogram.

[image]

---

I recognize that I could calculate the area of the parallelogram using vector cross products, but I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The idea with the vector product is the correct one.

The vectors are $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,2)$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

lets put the start of the cut at the origin.

Before it is cut, the plank extends indefinitely in the z-direction and 1 inch in the positive x and 1 inch in the positive y-direction.  That is, the sides of the plank are the xz and yz planes.

vector $u, v = (1,0,z_1), (0,1, z_2)$ represent the sides of the paralellogram.

$v$ has length $\sqrt 3$

$0^2 + 1^2 + z_2^2 = 3\\
z_2 = \sqrt2$

$u$ has length $\sqrt 2.$
$z_1 = 1$

Now that you have $u,v$ you can find $u\times v$